Connecting to the database server in a custom Docker network
I have a PostgreSQL database server running inside a container. I use Docker Compose to create the container. This container has no port mapping to host in the file, I do not want it to be accessible from public.
I am using IntelliJ Idea but I do not have any idea how to be able to connect to the container's network.
I know that I should be in the same network with the database server container before making connection to the database server.
As a strategy, can I create a dummy container in the same network for making connection purpose? so that I can configure a database connection.
Added docker-compose.yml file:
services:

  postgres-db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    container_name: postgres-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
      POSTGRES_USER: abc
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: abc
    networks:
      - auth-net
    volumes:
      - auth-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
networks:
  auth-net:
    external: true
    name: auth-net



In case when you just want to connect to the database from IDE DB viewer - you can find the IP address of the database in the internal docker network by this command:
docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <container name>
After that connect with the credentials which you defined for your DB.

I tried to connect by entering container's IP address in the host field 172.18.0.2 , default port is 5432 but it did not work. I tried also gateway port.

Could you provide how the db container was started?

I found one way. Instead of creating a dummy container, I created a ssh server container as an intermediary layer in the custom Docker network. I mapped the container port to host port.
I first logged in to the ssh server by entering username and password, then I was able to connect to database server using database credentials.
